# Update ListView within Fragment from DialogFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a ListView in Fragment, in which I want to add new item. DialogFragment is used to enter new item and on pressing "Yes" the item is dynamically added to the ListView. I have tried many solution but I cannot get it to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

In your Activity that implements interface defined in your DialogFragment

```
public void onCreateMatchDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog , String itemsToAdd) {
            //Your Fragment Class containing listview to be updated
        MyListViewFragmentClass fragment  = (MyListViewFragmentClass) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myListview);

        if(fragment != null){
                     //fragment is available
            fragment.addItemToListView(itemsToAdd);
        }

    }
```

Then in your fragment containing listview to add item dynamically

```
public void addItemToListView(itemToAdd){
      matchList.add(itemToAdd); //Add item to your dataset
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();//Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh
}
```

Comment: Can you post complete code of both classes ? I'm stuck in same situation

Comment: Here is good article about same situation : https://wuyingren.github.io/howto/2013/08/23/Updating-a-ListView-inside-a-Fragment-placed-on-a-ViewPager-on-DialogFragment-dismiss/